# DevExpress Cascading Combobox GridView DataBind

Tags: c#, gridview, combobox, devexpress, cascading

I have a `GridView` which contains a `TextField` of `BenefitName` (`string`) and a `ValueField` of `BenefitInfoKeySK` (`int`).

Originally I directly bound a `datasource` to the `combobox` and had distinct `TextField` and `ValueField` values. **(Code Sample 2)**

I updated my code to create 'cascading' comboboxes and the `TextField` value no longer displays in my `GridView` but it does display within the `comboBox` in my edit form.

> Why does the `TextField` render in my edit form `combobox` but *not* on my `GridView`?

**PartialView CodeSample 1** (Cascading combobox)

```
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "BenefitKey";
        column.Name = "BenefitKey";
        column.Caption = "Claim Type";
        column.Width = 200;
        column.Settings.AllowHeaderFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
        column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DefaultBoolean.True;
        column.Settings.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
        column.EditorProperties().ComboBox(p =>
        {
            p.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "BenefitClaimDetails", Action = "GetBenefitTypes", TextField = "BenefitName", ValueField = "BenefitInfoKeySK", headerEmployeeID = Model.BenefitHeaderEmployee };
            p.TextField = "BenefitName";
            p.ValueField = "BenefitInfoKeySK";
            p.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "ClaimTypeComboBox_BeginCallback";
            p.EnableCallbackMode = true;
            p.Width = 200;
            p.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
            p.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.ErrorText = "Claim Type cannot be blank";
            p.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithText;
        });
    });
```

**PartialView Code Sample 2** (basic combobox)

```
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "BenefitKey";
        column.Name = "BenefitKey";
        column.Caption = "Claim Type";
        column.Width = 200;
        column.Settings.AllowHeaderFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
        column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DefaultBoolean.True;
        column.Settings.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;

        column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
        var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
        comboBoxProperties.Width = 200;
        comboBoxProperties.DataSource = repository.GetBenefitListByEmployee(Model.BenefitHeaderEmployee);
        comboBoxProperties.TextField = "BenefitName";
        comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "BenefitInfoKeySK";
        comboBoxProperties.DropDownRows = 15;
        comboBoxProperties.ValueType = typeof(int);
        comboBoxProperties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
        comboBoxProperties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.ErrorText = "Claim Type cannot be blank";
        comboBoxProperties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithText;
    });
```

I have found that `p.TextField` and `p.ValueField` in code sample 1 do nothing. They can be removed with no effect on the code. However I must pass those fields in my `CallBackRoute` and assign them in the controller code:

**Controller Code**

```
    public ActionResult GetBenefitTypes(int claimantID, string textField, string valueField, string headerEmployeeID)
    {
        return GridViewExtension.GetComboBoxCallbackResult(p => {
            p.TextField = textField;
            p.ValueField = valueField;
            p.BindList(repository.GetBenefitListByEmployee(claimantID, headerEmployeeID));
        });
    }
```

As you can see, at the end both techniques call the same `Repository` method. Please let me know if I can elaborate on anything.

**EDIT**

I also attempted to modify Code Sample 1 by adding a columnType value and assigning a data source as shown below. This successfully displayed the `TextField` on my `GridView` but the `null` which I pass for `claimantID` prevented the Editor combobox from displaying any values.  For that reason I am also including the `JS` code where I assign `claimantID`.

**Modified PartialView Code Sample 1** (working grid view, no values in combobox)

```
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "BenefitKey";
        column.Name = "BenefitKey";
        column.Caption = "Claim Type";
        column.Width = 200;
        column.Settings.AllowHeaderFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
        column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DefaultBoolean.True;
        column.Settings.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
        column.EditorProperties().ComboBox(p =>
        {
            p.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "BenefitClaimDetails", Action = "GetBenefitTypes", TextField = "BenefitName", ValueField = "BenefitInfoKeySK", headerEmployeeID = Model.BenefitHeaderEmployee };
            p.TextField = "BenefitName";
            p.ValueField = "BenefitInfoKeySK";
            p.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "ClaimTypeComboBox_BeginCallback";
            p.EnableCallbackMode = true;
            p.Width = 200;
            p.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
            p.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.ErrorText = "Claim Type cannot be blank";
            p.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithText;
        });

        column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
        var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
        comboBoxProperties.DataSource = repository.GetBenefitListByEmployee(Model.BenefitHeaderEmployee, null);
        comboBoxProperties.TextField = "BenefitName";
        comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "BenefitInfoKeySK";
    });
```

**JS Code**

```
@*The follwing functions handle the Cascading Benefit Type combobox*@
function OnSelectedClaimantChanged() {
    BenefitClaimDetailsGridView.GetEditor("BenefitKey").PerformCallback();
}
function ClaimTypeComboBox_BeginCallback(s, e) {
    e.customArgs["claimantID"] = BenefitClaimDetailsGridView.GetEditor("DependentKey").GetValue();
}
```

I'm sorry to include so much code and not a working project, but the Solution is quite large. I hope this will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.

I started to comment out the `comboBoxProperties` section line by line to understand at what point the callback would begin failing and I found that it failed due to my declaration: `column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;`

After looking into how the `EditorProperties.Combobox()` was working I realized that in that section of code, `ComboBox` was utilizing the standard `MVCxColumnComboBoxProperties` rather than the `DevExpress GridView ComboBox`.

> I think the issue was that in the callback I was declaring the column type one way but then overriding it later on with my `comboBoxProperties` code.
>   The change which I made was changing
>   `var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;` 
>   to
>
> `var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as MVCxColumnComboBoxProperties;`

The finalized working code is here. For somebody trying to put this together themselves: In order to achieve cascading comboboxes which display text but are stored with a different value you will need the following.

1. In your partial view give the 'initiator' column a `SelectedIndexChanged` event such as this:

   ```
   settings.Columns.Add(column =>
   {
       column.FieldName = "DependentKey";
       column.Name = "DependentKey";
       column.Caption = "Claimant";
       column.Width = 300;
       column.Settings.AllowHeaderFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
       column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DefaultBoolean.True;
       column.Settings.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;

       column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
       var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
       /*Get an employee model for the current employee and pass that to the Depoendents method to get their list of dependents*/
       comboBoxProperties.DataSource = repository.GetDependentDropdownList(repository.GetCurrentEmployee(employeeID: Model.BenefitHeaderEmployee).DimEmployee);
       comboBoxProperties.TextField = "DependentName";
       comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "DependentKeySK";
       comboBoxProperties.DropDownRows = 15;
       comboBoxProperties.ValueType = typeof(int);
       comboBoxProperties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
       comboBoxProperties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.ErrorText = "Claimant cannot be blank";
       comboBoxProperties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithText;
       comboBoxProperties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedClaimantChanged";
   });
   ```
2. In the column which is to be influenced you will need to declare it as such (this is the final version of my Code Sample 1 / Code Sample 2 from above):

   ```
   settings.Columns.Add(column =>
   {
       column.FieldName = "BenefitKey";
       column.Name = "BenefitKey";
       column.Caption = "Claim Type";
       column.Width = 200;
       column.Settings.AllowHeaderFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
       column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DefaultBoolean.True;
       column.Settings.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
       column.EditorProperties().ComboBox(p =>
       {   /*Populate the combobox with valid values based on the selected dependentKey*/
           p.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "BenefitClaimDetails", Action = "GetBenefitTypes", TextField = "BenefitName", ValueField = "BenefitInfoKeySK", headerEmployeeID = Model.BenefitHeaderEmployee };
           p.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "ClaimTypeComboBox_BeginCallback";
           p.Width = 200;
           p.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
           p.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.ErrorText = "Claim Type cannot be blank";
           p.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithText;
       });

       /*Display the BenefitName in the gridView. The Callback method TextField and ValueField only influence the comboBox in the Editor window*/
       var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as MVCxColumnComboBoxProperties;
       comboBoxProperties.Width = 200;
       comboBoxProperties.DataSource = repository.GetBenefitListByEmployee(Model.BenefitHeaderEmployee);
       comboBoxProperties.TextField = "BenefitName";
       comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "BenefitInfoKeySK";
   });
   ```
3. Create the `JS` code on your `Index` page - my code is above
4. Create the `ActionResult` in your controller - my code is above

With those 4 pieces in place you can cascade the comboBoxes and properly display them in the grid as well